# How to show the count selected values in the label of select box(i.e Select Option)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the jQuery multiselect api to select multiple values in my application,but what i want that,when i click on a button beside that multiselect box all the selected values should be fetched.But i am not able to do that ,Here i am posting my code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/jquery.multiSelect.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/jquery.multiSelect.js">

</script>

<h1>Form Submission Test</h1>

<p>Testing to ensure the correct values are actually passed when the form is submitted.</p>
<select name="region" id="regionHome">
<option value="MDC">MDC</option>
<option value="LAC">LAC</option>
<option value="BRO/WPB">BRO/WPB</option>
<option value="NOE">NOE</option>
<option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchByDate()" class="searchButton">

<script>
$("#regionHome").multiSelect();

  function searchByDate() {

alert("There are " + $('input[name="regionHome[]"]:checked').length + " boxes selected");
var foo = [];
$('input[name="regionHome[]"]:checked').each(function (i, selected) {
    $( 'div.regionHome' ).replaceWith( "<p>Test</p>" );
    foo[i] = $(selected).val();
    alert(foo[i]);
   });
 }
   </script>
```

Selection along with count is here i am trying to show the count of each selected values in the label with each select i.e when ever i  will select a value the count will be updated in the label fiddle is here

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbtceq2m/3)

Comment: What do you mean by "jQuery multiselect api"? Are you using a plug-in? (if you are, specify which one). What error do you get in the console? Also, the code is messy (missing some closing curly braces), and I feel like things are not in the scope that they should be (looking at that `$("#regionHome").change()`)

Comment: I am using jQuery multiselect api

Comment: Also i am  posting the code from where i am taking the reference

Comment: `<title>jQuery MultiSelect Plugin Tests</title>` You are using MultiSelect plugin, could you include a link to the page in which you get the code?

Comment: posting complete code just a minute sir

Comment: No hurries. Just noting that there are several multiselect plugins online, and knowing which one you are using will be helpful :)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro posted complete code sir ..please take a look

Comment: Where are you getting the jquery.multiselect.js file?

Comment: from my local ..multiselect is working properly.i am just asking how to pick multiple values from it

Comment: Again, your code doesn't help without knowing what jquery.multiselect.js is. You need to understand that `multiselect()` is not part of the jQuery API, it is a plugin that somebody developed and you are using it. You are not specifying where you got it or what it does, you don't specify what error (if any) you get in the console, you are not providing all the code to be able to reproduce your problem (read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... you are not helping others help you

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro    http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/ you can see

Comment: Thanks! After checking the plugin page, it was easy to reproduce the error and figure it out. Check the answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the link to the place where the plugin is located. After checking it, the error is a simple typographical mistake.

Use this:

```
// notice the capital S in multiSelect
$("#regionHome").multiSelect();
```

Instead of:

```
// all lower case = BAD
$("#regionHome").multiselect();
```

You can see it working with your code on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gbtceq2m/

---

Now that the multiSelect works, you need to realize that the initial `select` "doesn't exist anymore" (not in the same way). It has been replaced by a set of checkboxes that mimic a multiselect. So you need to update the selector to work with those checkboxes instead of with the select options:

```
$('input[name="regionHome[]"]:checked').each(function (i, selected) {
    foo[i] = $(selected).val();
    alert(foo[i]);
});
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/gbtceq2m/1/

Comment: @lucifer Sorry, I lost track of the question trying to get the multiSelect plugin to work. I have updated the solution so now it works with the multiSelect correctly

Comment: can you give the functionality that will give the count of selected values in the lebel

Comment: You could use the `.length` property for count the number of selected values. Just like this:  `$('input[name="regionHome[]"]:checked').length`. You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/gbtceq2m/3/

Comment: thanks  a lot one more thing i would like to ask you that select option is coming from nultiselect js libray i want to show the count of the selected values in that position on each selection the count will show there?

Comment: @Alvaeo Let me show you what i have done,i am editing my post

Comment: I don't fully understand your edit. Could you add a more extended description, please?

Comment: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/ want to implement this

Comment: Or just http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/ from where i found it

Comment: i have explained please see

Comment: All that you are requesting is already in the plugin. The problem is that it is an old plugin only supported by old versions of jQuery. If you change the jQuery version to 1.6.4, it works without making any change to the code. Whatever solution I give you to support newer versions of jQuery would be hacky and not ideal. You should check if there is a newer version of the plugin that works with modern versions of jQuery. If not, I'd highly recommend to go for a different plugin. You can see the behavior you want here: http://jsfiddle.net/gbtceq2m/4/ (same code, just changing jQuery to 1.6.4)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing drop down should allow multiple selection?

If so, you'd have to add `multiple` attribute to your select drop down like below:

```
<select class="js-region-list-box" name="region" id="regionHome" multiple="true">
    <option value="MDC">MDC</option>
    <option value="LAC">LAC</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Also, jQuery provides `.val()` method which can be used to get value out of any form field.

In case of select box (drop down allowing multiple selection) `.val()` will return all the selected values separated by a comma

More Info about `val()` is [here](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

Based on above info.

You could approach it like this

**html**

```
<select class="js-region-list-box" name="region" id="regionHome" multiple="true">
    <option value="MDC">MDC</option>
    <option value="LAC">LAC</option>
    <option value="BRO/WPB">BRO/WPB</option>
    <option value="NOE">NOE</option>
    <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
</select>
<button class="js-regions">Get Regions</button>
```

**js**

```
var $regionListBox = $(".js-region-list-box");

$(".js-regions").on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var selectedRegions = $regionListBox.val();    

    alert(selectedRegions);
});
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/zdb06jp8/

Comment: No This will not help i can not use multiple = true here